# Can you delete your ssh key?

Tags: shell, ssh, remote-access

Is it possible for you to delete your main ssh key? I'm talking about the one that you would use in order to remotely access your computer. And if this is possible, what would happen? Would you not be able to access your machine remotely at all, or would anyone be able to access it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A server has public keys for the people who can log in to it.

The private key is held on the computer(s) seeking access.

If you delete your public key (from `.ssh/authorized_keys`) then you can no longer access that account with the matching private key. But someone with access could always add it back for you.

If you delete your private key (`.ssh/id_rsa`, etc.) then you lose the ability to connect to any accounts on any servers that have the public key entry for that key in the `authorized_keys` file and in order to regain access to those (or other) accounts/servers you need to generate a new key pair and have someone with appropriate access update the `authorized_keys` files.

At no point does any of this grant (or remove) access to anyone else anywhere.